# Unable to get proper value of inner class variable in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to access an inner class variable and could not achieve it.

```
public int foo {

public int valueofX() {
    abc a = new foo().new abc();
    return a.getX(); 
}
private final class abc {
    private int x =0; // this value is changed later in the code

        public int getX() {
         return x; //this always give me 0
        }   
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run instead of this incomplete code?

Answer (score 0):

you have declared foo as an int - shouldn't this be your outer class?

```
public class foo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    foo f = new foo();
    int x = f.valueofX();
}
public int valueofX() {
    abc a = new abc();
    return a.getX();
}

private final class abc {
    private int x = 1; 

    public int getX() {
        return x; 
    }
}

}
```

x is 1 here...

Do you really want to be creating a new abc() everytime you call valueOfX() - chances are you want abc to be a field of foo:

```
public class foo {

    private abc a = new abc();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        foo f = new foo();
        int x = f.valueofX();
    }
    public int valueofX() {

        return a.getX();
    }

    private final class abc {
        private int x = 1;

        public int getX() {
            return x; 
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code:

```
public int foo { 

public int valueofX() {
    abc a = new abc(); //You create a new 'abc' element and store it in 'a'
    return a.getX(); /*Here you access the method 'getX()' from 'a', and 'a' 
                       contains and 'abc' object. It gives you back the value x,
                       and it's with this method you could modify x.
                     */
}

    private final class abc {
        private int x = 0; // this value is changed later in the code

            public int getX() {
                 return x; //this always give me 0
            }              /*CORRECTION: This will give you 'X', that initially 
                             has the value of 0 */
    }
```

}

For accessing the 'x' variable of 'a' (abc class), you have to get the use the merthod that returns it.

---

If you only want to access 'x' value, you do what I've written.

```
a.valueOfX(); //This will return X, you can store it, operate with it, use it.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this implementation

```
 public class OuterClass {
    public int valueofX() {
        abc a = new OuterClass().new abc();
        a.setX(1);
        return a.getX();
    }
    private final class abc {
        private int x =0; // this value is changed later in the code

        public int getX() {
            return x; //this always give me 0
        }
        public void setX(int x)
        {
            this.x = x;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String arr[])
    {
        OuterClass x = new OuterClass();
        System.out.println(x.valueofX());
    }
    }
```